# Приложение зависает при использовании VK SDK для Android

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Проблема с выполнением VKSdk.login. Всё вроде проходит нормально, открывается окно входа, я нажимаю разрешить и всё. Вместо моего приложения открывается просто чёрный экран и через время появляется окно с предложением закрыть неотвечающее приложение.

Фрагмент кода MainActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ONCREATE");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        VKSdk.wakeUpSession(this, new VKCallback<VKSdk.LoginState>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(VKSdk.LoginState res) {
                switch (res) {
                    case LoggedOut:
                        VKSdk.login(MainActivity.this, VKScope.AUDIO);
                        break;
                    case LoggedIn:
                        break;
                    case Pending:
                        break;
                    case Unknown:
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Если вы добавите лог падения, будет просто супер!

Comment: @miha_dev а лога нет. Приложение просто виснет. Именно не ошибка вылетает, а виснет. Ну точнее Лог есть, но в нём ошибок никаких нет

Comment: вы делаете VKSdk.initialize(Context applicationContext); в классе Application ?

Comment: Если приложение падает, то стек ошибки всегда есть. Вы искали лог в logcat?

Comment: @miha_dev да, я инициализировал СДК. В логе ничего нет. После нажатия разрешить в логе ничего не появляется.

Comment: А в манифесте прописана активиьи для VK? В доках пишут, что она нужна

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, активити прописана.

Comment: @ДимаРодионов Попробуйте прописать VKSdk.login(this, scope); вместо части вашего кода в onCreate. Проверьте, есть ли ошибки. Замените scope на свои права.